# Миксин для отзывчивого свойства

Tags: css, sass, scss

```
      p {
             font-size: 15px;
           }
           @media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
             p {
               font-size: calc(15px + 3 * ((100vw - 850px) / 270));
             }
           }
           @media screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
             p {
               font-size: 18px;
             }
      }
```

Помогите сделать миксин, чтобы туда вписывал: свойство, мин, макс и диапазон, в котором происходит измерение. Если не указал ничего в диапазоне, тогда берется переменная длинны контейнера и 320 px